# viewPager Adapter not being updated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I am trying to update adapter(MyCollegePagerAdapter) from CollegeHTMLParse.class. However, even though I created an object and called the notifyDataSetChanged() method on it, noting is showing up on the fragments. Can you tell me if there is anything wrong with my code as I have googled for solution for weeks now and after trying for hours upon hours, I am not able to figure out the issue.

Here is the CollegeHTMLParse class:

```
public class CollegeHTMLParse extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ArrayList<String> colleges = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> accepted = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> link = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> location = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> tuition = new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseDatabase mRef;
    DatabaseReference database;
    public static ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    MyCollegePagerAdapter adapter = new MyCollegePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    public void onCreate(String CollegeCode) {
        colleges.clear();
        accepted.clear();
        link.clear();
        location.clear();
        tuition.clear();
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://successway18.firebaseio.com/");
        database = mRef.getReference().child("CollegeCodes").child("30");
        database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                setCollegeValues(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void setCollegeValues(String values) {
        colleges.add(values);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < colleges.size()) {
            database.child(colleges.get(i)).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    setDetailsValues(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            i++;
        }

    }

    private void setDetailsValues(String details) {
        data.add(details);
        if (data.size() == 4) {
            accepted.add(data.get(0));
            link.add(data.get(1));
            location.add(data.get(2));
            tuition.add(data.get(3));
            data.clear();
        }
        update();
    }

    private void update() {           
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your pager adapter

```
  @Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I have implemented it. But the adapter for some reason is still unable to pick up the notifyDataSetChanged() call and thereby not displaying any of the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase query runs in the worker thread, so you have to run notifyDataSetChanged in the main thread.
Try to use the below code in the function update()

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I have implemented it. But the adapter for some reason is still unable to pick up the notifyDataSetChanged() call and thereby not displaying any of the fragments.

Comment: You may have to post your adapter code so everybody can have an overview about your problem.